# Is prolific an approving word or neutral word?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, pejorative-language

I thought it was an approving word which is used to describe the diligence of a producer or artist and therefore the abundance of their productivity.Then I just knew that it can also be used to describe serial killers:a prolific serial killer which surprised me very much.So I wonder if it is a neutral word.

Comment: Prolific has no connotation, good or bad in itself, just like many other adjectives.  It all depends on the noun it refers to.  e.g. "a planned trip", "a planned murder".

Comment: There may have been irony in the phrase "prolific serial killer" when it was first used, as prolific is indeed normally applied to things like writing/art. These days "prolific serial killer" has become a very commonly used phrase and any irony is lost. Similarly in "spree killer", a spree is normally a good thing, e.g. a shopping spree. But a lot of criminologists seem to have a dark sense of humor.

Comment: In and of itself, I'd say ***prolific*** is "neutral", compared to ***abundant*** (positive) and ***rife*** (negative).

Comment: What's an "approving" word? What's a "neutral" word? What's a "disapproving" word?

Comment: @Drew Yes, used in non-precisionist ways here. But obviously, here, 'approving' is intended to convey 'connoting the commentator's opinion of meritorious productivity being involved, or any generally flourishing state. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Prolific" is a metaphor when used not in its literal sense. It is normally favorable, e.g., a "prolific" author, but can imply that the person or group is giving metaphorical life to so many offspring that they can't all be of high quality, and the progenitor should be more selective in the offspring he chooses to keep / publish / promote / etc.

Answer (score -1):

A neutral word in nature, though many jump at applying it to positive things. It depends on what it is being applied to.

*For instance*

> The rise of depression was prolific in her journey to becoming a killer.

Comment: What does it mean for a word to be "approving in nature" or not?

Comment: How can "rise" be prolific?

Answer (score -1):

The word "prolific" itself is generally a neutral word, simply meaning "producing or capable of producing in large quantities." However, the context in which it is used can give it an approving or disapproving connotation. You can try providing the context.